# self parent/child relation with mongoose query all parents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to create self relation with mongoose... Later I will need query which will show all parents and their childrens. Also all childrens can be parents...

Here is my shcema:

```
var codeSchema = {
    code: {
        type: String
    },
    childCode: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: false
    }],
    parentCode: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: false
    }]
};
```

How can I crete query for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use ref attr in childCode and parentCode.set ref attr to the collection name and you can use populate function to get the data.

Example : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html